# Local Database for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce, isolatedstorage

I have started working on windows phone development recently. I have come across how to maintain relational database locally from this link : [LINQ TO SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202876(v=vs.105).aspx)

The program performs operations on the `.sdf` file.

My question is does the LINQ TO SQL ORM use the SQL Server CE database by default?

If not then which database is it using by default?

And is isolated storage used as a container to contain the database file?

Comment: Yes and yes. (you can also store in the install folder, but then the database is read-only)

Comment: @ErikEJ The .sdf file is the SQL CE database file?

Comment: Yes - some links to study here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/07/windows-phone-sql-server-compact.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server CE uses it's own methods to store the database within isolated storage.

If you want to use SQL Server CE with linq, then you need to define your model classes as a `System.Data.Linq.Table` object, which will be placed in a class of type `System.Data.Linq.DataContext`.

Calling `SubmitChanges` on the `DataContext` will push all changes in the context instance to the isolated storage backend automatically as an SQL Server CE database.

```
public class MyDataContext : DataContext
{
    private static MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();

    public Table<Person> People;
    public Table<Item> Items;

    // pass the connection string to the base class.
    public MyDataContext() : base("DataSource=isostore:/data.sdf", mappingSource)
    {
    }

    ~MyDataContext()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}

MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();

// do stuff here

db.SubmitChanges();
```